# Can I use NBN FTTC directly with only an NBN Connection Box and PC (without a router)?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, pppoe

The NBN is Australia's **National Broadband Network**; a primarily-fibre network with last-mile copper in most places.  As [explained here](https://www.nbnco.com.au/learn/network-technology), NBN connections are divided into 7 types - FTTP (Premises), FTTB (Building), FTTC ("Curb" or Street pit), FTTN (Node), and HFC (Hybrid Fibre Coaxial), Fixed Wireless, and Satellite.  Unfortunately, each type has its own quirks and requirements.  This question is about *[FTTC](https://www.nbnco.com.au/learn/network-technology/fibre-to-the-curb-explained-fttc)* (and possibly others), which consists of a fibre link to a pit outside the premises, and existing copper (previously ADSL) from the pit to the premises' original telephone line.

For FTTC connections, an "NBN Connection Box" is provided by NBNCo, usually along with an "NBN-approved" router (by your ISP, for an additional cost).  There has been mention that connecting without an "NBN-Approved" modem may cause your NBN connection to be blacklisted (time-delay) but this may only apply to directly-fibre based connections.  It's unclear if this applies to FTTC connections.

This question is related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1564393/what-is-a-nbn-fttc-connection-device/1564395#1564395) about **the function of the NBN Connection Box on an FTTC connection**.

In it, [the top answer](https://superuser.com/a/1564395/160891) says about the "NBN Connection Box":

> More specifically, it is a VDSL2 modem preconfigured for NBN FTTC. Like any other modem, it acts as an interface between the analog signal travelling along the copper pair (your house lead-in) from the DPU in the pit, and an Ethernet network.

So, if it is a *VDSL2 modem* and, specifically, **an ethernet on the other side**, other than sharing the connection **why do we need a router in this diagram?**

[image: NBN FTTC diagram showing Your compatible WiFi gateway]

Let's say I don't want to share or to provide Wi-Fi or some other telephone.  I just want a wired NBN connection to my PC.  If the ethernet cable is really ethernet, can I safely do this?

[image: NBC FTTC diagram with ethernet cable connected directly from modem to PC]

The only other thing I can see is:

- the authentication requirement (PPPoE)
- the "NBN-Approved" requirement for the router (if it exists for FTTC).

So, **is it possible to wire it this way (without a router) and then use PPPoE in software over an ordinary Gigabit LAN adapter?**

If so, how?  (I am proficient in Windows, Linux, and Mac networking, so I can translate any solution between the three.  Any suggestion will do.)

If not, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What one needs to keep in mind is that the NBN strictly provides a layer 2 connection that ends at (for FTTC) the NCD.

Anything beyond that, including any router, is supplied or required at your RSP's discretion.

There is nothing on the NBN's network that stops you from simply plugging a computer directly into the NBN-supplied network termination device. This holds true for FTTP, FTTC, and HFC at the very least - it may also hold for FW and Sat but I'm not too familiar with those. NBN FTTN ends up as a special case because the VDSL2 modem is under customer/RSP control, though you can set it up like the others by disabling any routing component of such a modem.

Where things actually get tricky is what is allowed and the final configuration required depends entirely on your RSP, not the NBN. These are often documented by the RSP, or may otherwise be available via support channels.

The diagram you refer to only illustrates a common configuration that can be understood by your average consumer. You'll typically find more information buried in your RSP's website or forums as "BYO router settings" or similar.

---

There are three basic connection types commonly used on the NBN:

- Plain IPoE is very common. This is effectively just raw IP packets in Ethernet, same as your normal LAN connections. Usually it is paired with DHCP to fetch an address (and only supports one address at a time, so you'll need a router with NAT to connect more than one device). In this scenario you usually *can* simply plug in a normal computer and have a working connection.
- Plain PPPoE is also quite common, and can be configured with any PPPoE client and provided an RSP-defined username and password.
- PPPoE with a VLAN is used by some, most infamously TPG. These are trickier to configure, as you will need to set up a VLAN-tagged interface as the parent. Not too difficult on Linux but may be driver-dependent on Windows. You then tell the PPP client to connect through that VLAN-tagged interface.

In all cases, I would recommend you make sure you have a firewall enabled and appropriately configured on the computer. Security-wise, it would be much like having a direct IPv6 address assigned with no external firewall.

The Whirlpool Forums [maintain a list](https://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/vdsl2_modem_routers_isp_settings) of known settings for RSPs. You can ignore the FTTN/VDSL2 section at the top if you are on FTTC, and just use the service provider settings below it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to wire it this way (without a router) and then use PPPoE in software over an ordinary Gigabit LAN adapter?

- **Technically**, there is no reason you can't just connect a PC to the VDSL modem and establish a PPPoE connection directly.

  - Once configured correctly, your computer will receive an IP from the ISP on a virtual PPPoE-specific interface (likely a globally routable IP address, but possibly not if the ISP is using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)), along with any DNS and routing information, and off you go!
  - You'll need to supply a number of configuration parameters including a username and password, but potentially more technical values too - MTU, VPI, VCP, LCP, VLAN, encapsulation, etc...
- **However**, you've already speculated that the ISP may have policies in place, potentially denying service to you for not using an "*approved*" router.
- **Additionally**, this would present a significant security concern - your PC would now be directly on the internet with no routing, [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) or firewall (aside from any provided by the OS) to protect you.

  - "*You're on your own*", and the system would only be as secure as you are able to make it - ignorance won't be any comfort here.
  - Out-of-the-box configuration is often not sufficient for this use-case.

---

> If so, how? (I am proficient in Windows, Linux, and Mac networking, so I can translate any solution between the three. Any suggestion will do.)

It should be as straight forward as:

1. Connect an Ethernet cable between the Modem's internal Ethernet port, and the PC
2. Install / configure a PPPoE client
3. Enjoy internet access

There are a number of guides for configuring PPPoE on Linux, but fundamentally: (on Ubuntu / Debian <sup>[ref](https://wiki.debian.org/PPPoE)</sup>)

```bsh
apt update
apt install ipppd pppoe pppoeconf

# use pppoeconf to guide you through configuration and initial bringup of the interface
pppoeconf ${interface}
```

I would be surprised if Windows and Mac didn't have some way to establish a PPPoE connection too.

**NOTE:** I've not actually done this recently, and don't have notes to hand, apologies.

---

> If not, why not?

I would ***strongly*** advise ***against*** doing this, especially if this system is intended to be used as a workstation or used by users who aren't accustomed to administering systems that are directly connected to the internet.

If you know what you're doing ***and*** are doing one of the following, then go for it:

- Building a router to serve the rest of your home, that is carefully administered, and with a functional firewall - *do not do this for a business unless you have the experience*.
- Building a server that is carefully administered, with a functional firewall, and with specific services running.

  - **NOTE:** Many ISPs will block common ports (e.g: 80 / 443), making it impossible to host services on standard ports (or potentially at all).

Given that you will have no NAT or firewall between your computer and the internet, it is *very* easy to mis-configure a service or inadvertently start a piece of software that silently opens listening sockets. Additionally, vulnerabilities are frequently found in older software, so even if the system was thought to be secure at the time, it can quickly become stale and vulnerable.

This provides a way in for people who are *routinely* and *frequently* scanning the internet for vulnerable hosts. The "*[Internet Census 2012](http://census2012.sourceforge.net/paper.html)*" showed that it is possible to scan the entire internet in as little as ~16.5 hours (it's likely even faster in the 8 years since).

Windows has certainly had a bad reputation for not being very secure in the past (something that is getting better over time), but the point still stands that these systems aren't really intended or expected to be directly connected to the internet.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no requirement for PPP of any sort. It really depends on your RSP, e.g. ABB provides a IPoE connection.

Comment: Interesting - I've not come across a VDSL line that doesn't use PPP, and I have no direct experience with NBN (I'm in the UK, perhaps not best suited to comment)... I noticed that [here](https://help.australiabroadband.com.au/support/solutions/articles/44000687028-australia-broadband-settings) they seem to only mention PPPoE, and are _very_ strict on permitted equipment. Is it safe to stick with PPPoE given that OP calls it out specifically?

Comment: If anything, [the majority](https://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/vdsl2_modem_routers_isp_settings) of NBN RSPs use IPoE. Though TPG is a popular cheap option and uses one of the more complex configs available (PPPoE over VLAN). I don't think "Australia Broadband" has any significant customer base; the similarly-named Aussie Broadband (...who came first?) is quite popular among power users.

Comment: I also wouldn't assume anything from the OP mentioning PPPoE, since the question as a whole is quite broad. They may be familiar with PPPoE from previous ADSL experiences, as Australians moved over fairly recently.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the info. I'll leave my answer as-is  (no longer at the computer / yours stands well) ... sounds like you know the topic - can you offer any feedback on my advice to avoid doing this if at all possible?

Comment: It's perfectly valid advice, though I would expect a power user to take the detail you have gone into re: risks and reasons into consideration and protect against them. Your answer is a great one - I only added another to offer more NBN-centric details as they may be somewhat different from what is used in other countries.

Comment: Thanks.  I mention PPPoE because I, personally, have FTTB and both my current (FlipConnect/FlipTV) and my previous one (Exetel) required PPPoE for the connection (which is "ETH WAN").  I did try VDSL but it didn't work on FTTB.  Another client has FTTP which seems to require PPPoE over VDSL (and won't work on "ETH WAN").  A colleague with HFC tells me he doesn't need any authentication at all.  So confusing!

Comment: @tu-ReinstateMonica-dorduh VDSL is not involved in FTTP at all. Whether you need PPPoE or not (on FTTP too) depends entirely on your RSP. Really, the NBN technology (apart from FTTN) doesn't affect what equipment you attach, as apart from FTTN you end up with the exact same Ethernet port.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is entirely possible and detailed in the article
[Testing your nbn internet using a direct connection](https://www.letsbemates.com.au/mate/nbn-speed-test-direct-connection/),
with a very good chance that it applies here:

**Step 1: Connect your computer directly to your nbn connection device**

Take an RJ-45 Ethernet cable and plug one end into the active port on your
nbn connection device. Plug the other end into your computer’s LAN/Ethernet port.

**Step 2 : Configure with Microsoft Windows operating system**

1. Navigate to "Control Panel", then click on "Network and Internet"
2. Click on "Network and Sharing Centre"
3. Click on "Setup a new connection or network"
4. Click on "Connect to the Internet"
5. Click "set up a new connection anyway"
6. Choose "Broadband (PPPoE)"
7. In the "Username" field, enter your supplied connection username
8. In the "Password" field, enter your supplied connection password
9. Click "Connect".

## However, this is a bad idea.

Your computer is completely exposed to the internet and the IP assigned to your
cable modem resolves directly to your home PC.
Any vulnerability on your computer (a port left open, an exploit, a known
vulnerability in your OS) is completely accessible to anyone on the internet scanning
your public IP segment.

*You can also drive a car without insurance or a seat belt,
but that doesn’t mean it’s the best course of action.*

The router does not only routing, but is also the first line of defense between
you and any possible attack from the internet. This is one of its most
important function, which almost all routers do quite successfully.

The D-Link answer to this question in the brochure
[Do you need a Modem Router or a Router](https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/wc-prod-pim/Asset_Documents/Do%20you%20need%20a%20Modem%20Router%20or%20a%20Router.pdf),
where it makes no mention of any possibility of direct connection,
but does recommend some D-Link routers.
In short, you need a Modem Router for VDSL (FTTN CONNECTION),
and only a Router for all other types of connection
(fiber, cable, satellite).

Comment: Wow. That's a really helpful link.  And yes, I'm aware of the risks connecting a machine directly to the internet.  I'm not a novice and I run quite a few servers here and there in various DCs, but yes, the warning may be appropriate for most.  In my case I need this specifically so that I can expose it this way as it reduces a point of failure by removing an unnecessary router.

Comment: Should be noted that your first link is to *Mate*, an RSP, and their advice will not necessarily apply to other RSPs. More specifically, the instructions provided **will not work** for RSPs that use IPoE, or PPPoE with a VLAN (the two of which make up the majority of RSPs). You've also misattributed the second link: that's not an NBNCo publication, that's a D-Link publication. Content of it looks alright, though obviously the example models are all D-Link. And being a router/modem manufacturer... it's unsurprising D-Link brochure doesn't describe a scenario without one.

Comment: @Bob: The D-Link error cropped up when I replaced one link by a better one - corrected and thanks. Anyway, the important part here is if the Mate advice applies to NBN, and I think there is a very good chance of that.

Comment: @harrymc Perhaps a bit of background will help. The NBN primarily describes and includes the physical infrastructure - generally, they provider a layer 2 network between the RSP (Retail Service Provider) and the home/business. Everything between the POI (Point of Interconnect) and the Ethernet port on the NTD/NCD is part of the NBN network and generally transparent; the RSP connection sits on top of that network. FTTN is a bit of an exception since the customer must provide their own VDSL2 modem, but the same concept applies.

Comment: *Most importantly, the NBN network does not care about layer 3. At all. It doesn't know about, or care, what kind of IP packets you send over it. It doesn't care about PPP.* You don't generalise Mate to NBN - Mate sits on top of NBN. Like TPG sits on top of NBN. Like Telstra. Like Optus. Vodafone. Aussie Broadband. Superloop. etc. etc. etc.. This is significant because the specific protocols and authentication required to connect (PPPoE, "IPoE" which is just IP with DHCP, any VLAN requirements, etc.) vary by RSP *while using the same NBN network*.

Comment: Which is why, much like Attie's answer, I feel it is important to note that talking about PPPoE only addresses a small part of the question "can I/how do I connect a computer directly to a NBN internet connection", because without knowledge of which specific RSP is being used, there is a good chance that it's not a plain PPPoE connection. [The most complete list we have](https://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/vdsl2_modem_routers_isp_settings) has quite the number of different types, and the most popular RSPs by far (Telstra, TPG) are IPoE or PPPoE+VLAN respectively.

Comment: Sorry for the info dump; I just feel the network situation with NBN is rather unique and may be missed by those not familiar with it, leading to incomplete answers. Thanks for correcting the D-Link attribution.