# Could I run a NBN FTTP connection directly through a switch and ditch my WiFi router?

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet, fiber

The NBN is Australia's high-speed broadband network that is explained in [great detail here](https://superuser.com/questions/1565493/can-i-use-nbn-fttc-directly-with-only-an-nbn-connection-box-and-pc-without-a-ro), so I'll try to keep this question brief.

Unlike tudor -Reinstate Monica-, I'm on the [FTTP (Fibre To The Premises)](https://www.nbnco.com.au/learn/network-technology/fibre-to-the-premises-explained-fttp) connection option, which effectively means that I have a **completely fibre-based** connection, and I'm afraid that perhaps that makes the information in the linked thread irrelevant to me.

Anyway, the network topology within my house looks like this:

[image: h]

And the NTD is referred to as a "nbn connection box" in this image from NBN Co. (the company that administrates all this stuff):

[image: NBN Hardware]

So here's my question: **could I replace the V7610 with the TL-SG1008D and get another smaller switch to connect to the Archer C7?**

It would be great to hear from an NBN technician or some other Australian expert who actually knows definitively about the hardware that's provided/required for FTTP, and which technologies it implements.

MTIA for any advice, and apologies for the wall of text :-)

Comment: Love to know how your router could take out an RCD - not really possible unless the power supply melted! - Can you explain why you don't want wifi?

Comment: LOL sorry mate; I'm obviously a noob that doesn't really understand electricity properly...but I thought that maybe the router is drawing so much power now that it can't handle it, and that caused the RCD to keep tripping...which over two days and several resets, eventually wore it out. As mentioned, it was very old and protecting two separate circuits, instead of the modern, safer approach of having a separate RCD for every single circuit. And I don't want WiFi because I've been dealing with interference and other availability issues for 20+ years, and I'm well-and-truly over it!

Comment: Could I run a completely wired network without ANY devices using WiFi, and ditch my WiFi router?    .....    Yes of course.  Remove your wireless router and connect the Ethernet devices to the ISP modem Ethernet port. Use a switch if necessary for multiple connections.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: I misunderstood the setup, the modem and the router devices are separate so half of this answer in invalid.**

**2.** Having optical fiber connection has nothing to do with your home network. The only relevant thing is your connection to the provider is handled by a modem. In your case, it is an optical modem+router in one package.

It is unlikely that that the modem+router itself would trip the RCD, especially if you weren't touching it. Unless it is full of spider webs and in a damp environment, where it shouldn't be anyway.

Also most electricians can reliably tell whether your washing machine is faulty or not.

If you still want to investigate the modem+router device, you should start by replacing the power supply. If the device is provided by the service provider, you must contact them directly for replacing the device or the external power supply.

**1.** Regarding the WIFI:

Why would want to disable it in the first place? Altough most likely it can be disabled in the current modem+router device, but I think you haven't thinked it through.

For example, you couldn't connect you mobile phone to your home network simply, only by some special ways, which are generally unreliably and require a lot of tinkering. (bluetooth, usb, etc.)

About your switching your modem into bridge mode:

- If the modem+router is provided by the services provider, you must ask them about this explicitly. At least to my knowledge, most modems provided by service providers cannot be switched to bridge mode by the customer.
- If it was purchased by you, then you must provide a lot more details to us about the device (model, probably screenshots from the configuration interface).

Comment: Hi and thanks for answering! Just curious though; when you're talking about my "modem+router", do you mean the V7610 or the NBN connection box?

Comment: And while I get your points about the difficulty of connecting a phone to Ethernet, I'm so sick to death of WiFi connection issues that have been plaguing me for 20+ years, that I really am willing to try anything at this point - besides spending hundreds or even thousands of dollars on a mesh system, or a better router.

Comment: I'm sorry, seems like I misunderstood part of your question. I thought your NBN connection box and the router were the same device, since where are live this setup is the common. Your question is clear after rereading, so it is my fault for misunderstanding it.
However, it is still not mentioned whether the V7610 is yours and you have full access to its configuration or not.

Comment: No worries mate, no apology necessary! We all make those kind of mistakes from time to time ;-) The V7610 was supplied by my ISP, but I have full access to its config. web page. I'm just worried that it's getting old and maybe it's time for an upgrade, but I'd like to avoid the cost of that if possible.

Comment: I think that if the consideration of replacing the current devices is only based on the RCD getting triggered frequently, then you don't need to replace it the devices themselves. AFAIK low voltage devices won't cause high enough leaking current to trigger most mains voltage RCDs. At least in normal environments, and when relatively clean.

Comment: Well, one could check if the grounding is correct in the mains outlet connecting to the power supply. On one occassion in an old house without grounding wires but grounding connector in the outlet, the mains voltage got out to the grounding connector, and somehow 50+ volts appeared on some metal parts of my laptop, shocking me a little a few times. The laptop was working normally otherwise, and I'm yet to find out how that happened. I only shared this part is because while generally unlikely for the router to trigger the RCD,

Comment: but it is somehow possible, and an eletrician can give better advices than me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150603/discussion-between-kenny83-and-hatalmasalma).